# Update each field in mongo db collection from map by providing key from another field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, collections, updating

I have javascript object with key, values . In mongo collection need to set a field based on another field as key from object.

```
    const object = require('../file.json'); 

    const collection1 = db.collection('name1');
    const collection1Array = await db.collection('name1').find({"field1":{$exists:true}}).toArray();
  
    if (!collection1Array.length) return;
  
    const updatedList = collection1Array.map((doc) => ({
      updateMany: {
          filter: {"field1":{$exists:true}},
          update: {
            $set: {
              'field2': object[field1],
             },
         },
        }
    }));

    await collection1.bulkWrite(updatedList);
```

But this code is not updating correct values in database. Same value is getting updated for all records. For example, I have

```
object = {k1:v1,k2:v2,k3:v3}
collection1=[{field1=k1,...},{field1=k2...}...]
output=[{field1=k1,field2=v1,...},{field1=k2,field2=v1,...}...]
expected output=[{field1=k1,field2=v1,...},{field1=k2,field2=v2,...}...]
```

What might be going wrong here, any help ?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#modify-a-field-using-the-values-of-the-other-fields-in-the-document